# Flutter - Dismiss system keyboard after tapping outside of AlertDialog widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have an AlertDialog widget that has a TextField widget as a child. I have configured the AlertDialog widget to not dismiss when the user taps outside of it. When the user taps on the TextField, the system keyboard is opened. I want to hide the system keyboard when the user taps outside of the AlertDialog. The current GestureDetector that I am using only dismisses the keyboard when the user taps on the AlertDialog, but outside of the TextField. Is the behavior that I'm seeking possible to achieve in Flutter? I have created a brand new flutter app and included *only* the relevant code to illustrate the use-case below.

**main.dart**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      await showDialog<String>(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async => false,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
            child: AlertDialog(
              content: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  TextField(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });

    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any Dialog in Flutter, basically, is a Route that opens on top of the current one.
When **barrierDismissible** is set to true - tap on the barrier triggers a **Navigator.pop()** method.

Since you have **WillPopScope** - you can utilize it's **onWillPop** to do the thing you need:

```dart
onWillPop: () async {
            final currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
            if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus && currentFocus.focusedChild != null) {
              FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
            }

            return false;
          },
```

Don't forget to:

1. Set barrierDismissible to true (or remove it since it's true by default)
2. Remove GestureDetector

Comment: I'm looking forward to giving this a try. I'll follow up after I give it a go. I appreciate the answer - you gave a very clear and concise explanation. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

I've found the easiest way to do it,
now you can use `onTapOutside` in the TextField widget

```
 TextField(
       onTapOutside: (event) {
                  print('onTapOutside');
                  FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                },)
```

This is called for each tap that occurs outside of the[TextFieldTapRegion] group when the text field is focused.

or you can use

```
       FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
```

if `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();` this cause any problem.

Comment: Simple and effective, thank you.